# Multiple values returned from multiple criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to adapt the code found on this site at this link.

[Return multiple rows of data in vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49903793/return-multiple-rows-of-data-in-vba)

I am needing to look at the info in columns A and B, then pull the matching records based on A and B from columns C thru H.

There will be multiple matches due to the job being worked on multiple dates.

To learn and understand what's happening, I am trying to build code one column at a time. What I have so far runs w/o errors, but all I receive is the value 1000 in J2.  I am not receiving 4172633414. Also, I do not know if J2 has the value from cell A2 or C2. Only gives the one value of 1000 instead of looping through all entries in columns A and B. In real life, columns A and B have 124 records, columns C thru H have 8,673 entries to select from.

I am hopeful that I am not too far off with my coding attempt. Posting the spreadsheet info was a challenge so I am hoping that it is readable. Thank you in advance.

Columns A and C have the header CNumber. B and D are JobNumber. E thru H are Hours, Units, Date, Branch respectively. This is a very abbreviated showing of what I have to work with.

```
CNumber JobNumber   CNumber JobNumber Hours Units   Date    Branch  
1000    4172633414  1000    1955126105  575 100 7/19/2018   3  
1002    1463149151  1000    1955126105  600 144 7/20/2018   3  
1004    1955126105  1000    1955126105  200 2.5 6/25/2018   3  
1005    90999997    1000    4172633414  575 675 7/9/2018    3  
1007    3965310303  1000    4172633414  100 5   7/10/2018   3  
1008    1463149151  1002    381134312   300 46  6/29/2018   3  
1011    3163689368  1002    382309308   575 88  8/22/2018   3  
1012    3965310303  1002    1013397112  600 139 9/21/2018   3  
1013    1955126105  1002    1463149151  300 71  6/29/2018   3  
1016    1463149151  1002    1463149151  575 60  7/2/2018    3  
1017    1463149151  1002    1463149151  375 77  7/5/2018    3  
1018    1463149151  1004    1955126105  575 7.25 6/25/2018  3
```

Below is the very abbreviated result I am looking for. Since CNumber 1000 has JobNumber 4172633414 above in columns A and B. He has 2 matching entries in C and D and related info below. CNumber 1002 has JobNumber 1463149151 above and has 3 matching entries below.

```
CNumber JobNumber   Hours Units Date    Branch  
1000    4172633414  575 675 7/9/2018    3  
1000    4172633414  100 5   7/10/2018   3  
1002    1463149151  300 71  6/29/2018   3  
1002    1463149151  575 60  7/2/2018    3  
1002    1463149151  375 77  7/5/2018    3  
1004    1955126105  575 7.25 6/25/2018  3  
1004    1955126105  575 5   6/26/2018   3  
1005    90999997    575     6/25/2018   3  
1005    90999997    250     6/26/2018   3
```

---

```
Sub MultiLookup()
Dim RowNumber, ClientCount As Integer
Dim ClientNumber() As Variant
Dim JobNumber() As Variant
Dim i As Integer
RowNumber = 0
ClientCount = 0
'everything on one sheet if possible
Sheets("TestJobs").Activate 'sheet name with all info
Range("A2").Activate

Do While ActiveCell.Offset(RowNumber) <> ""
    If ActiveCell.Offset(RowNumber) = ActiveCell.Offset(RowNumber, 2) _
        And ActiveCell.Offset(RowNumber, 1) = ActiveCell.Offset(RowNumber, 3) Then

        ClientCount = ClientCount + 1
        ReDim Preserve ClientNumber(ClientCount + 1)
        ReDim Preserve JobNumber(ClientCount + 1)

        ClientNumber(ClientCount) = ActiveCell.Offset(RowNumber, 2)
        JobNumber(ClientCount) = ActiveCell.Offset(RowNumber, 3)
    End If
    RowNumber = RowNumber + 1
Loop

Range("J1").Activate  'beginning cell to receive info (with row offset to J2), _
        but need J thru O
'Range("J1:K1").Activate 'this activates the two cells but no info appears _
    and does not offset to row 2.

For i = 0 To UBound(ClientNumber)
    ActiveCell.Offset(i) = ClientNumber(i)
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a loop.  Also, I prefer to grab the data and work with it in memory rather than going back and forth to the sheet.  Try this out:

Option Explicit

Sub MultiLookup()

Dim arrClientJob As Variant
Dim arrJobInfo   As Variant
Dim arrResult    As Variant

Dim lngLastRow   As Long
Dim intClient    As Integer
Dim intJobInfo   As Integer
Dim intCol       As Integer

'everything on one sheet if possible

```
On Error Resume Next
lngLastRow = Sheets("TestJobs").Range("A:A").Find( _
    What:="*", After:=Sheets("TestJobs").Range("A1"), _
    MatchCase:=False, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlValues, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
If Err <> 0 Then
    lngLastRow = 0
    Err.Clear
End If

If lngLastRow > 1 Then
    arrClientJob = Sheets("TestJobs").Range("A2").Resize(lngLastRow - 1, 2).Value
Else
    MsgBox "No client data, exiting", vbOKOnly
End If

lngLastRow = Sheets("TestJobs").Range("C:C").Find( _
    What:="*", After:=Sheets("TestJobs").Range("C1"), _
    MatchCase:=False, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlValues, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
If Err <> 0 Then
    lngLastRow = 0
    Err.Clear
End If

If lngLastRow > 1 Then
    arrJobInfo = Sheets("TestJobs").Range("C2").Resize(lngLastRow - 1, 6).Value
Else
    MsgBox "No ClientJob info found, exiting", vbOKOnly
End If

ReDim arrResult(LBound(arrJobInfo, 2) To UBound(arrJobInfo, 2), 1 To 1)

For intClient = LBound(arrClientJob, 1) To UBound(arrClientJob, 1)
    For intJobInfo = LBound(arrJobInfo, 1) To UBound(arrJobInfo, 1)
        If arrClientJob(intClient, 1) = arrJobInfo(intJobInfo, 1) _
        And arrClientJob(intClient, 2) = arrJobInfo(intJobInfo, 2) Then
            If arrResult(LBound(arrResult, 1), LBound(arrResult, 2)) > "" Then
                ReDim Preserve arrResult(LBound(arrResult, 1) To UBound(arrResult, 1), _
                    LBound(arrResult, 2) To UBound(arrResult, 2) + 1)
            End If
            For intCol = LBound(arrJobInfo, 2) To UBound(arrJobInfo, 2)
                arrResult(intCol, UBound(arrResult, 2)) = arrJobInfo(intJobInfo, intCol)
            Next intCol
        End If
    Next intJobInfo
Next intClient

Sheets("TestJobs").Range("J1").Resize(UBound(arrResult, 2) - LBound(arrResult, 2) + 1, _
    UBound(arrResult, 1) - LBound(arrResult, 1) + 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arrResult)
```

End Sub

Comment: Art, I copied your code and ran it.  It ran without errors, but no results appeared at J1 or anywhere else.  Thoughts?

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on the last line (Value =) and look at the local values, what do you see in arrResult?

Comment: `Sheets("TestJobs").Range("J1").Resize(UBound(arrResult, 2) - LBound(arrResult, 2) + 1, _
    UBound(arrResult, 1) - LBound(arrResult, 1) + 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arrResult)`

Comment: Having trouble replying & editing. Sorry. 
 `Sheets("TestJobs").Range("J1").Resize(UBound(arrResult, 2) - LBound(arrResult, 2) + 1, _
    UBound(arrResult, 1) - LBound(arrResult, 1) + 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arrResult)`  When I hover on the first UBound I receive:  UBound(arrResult, 2) = 1.  When I hover on the first LBound I receive:  LBound(arrResult, 2) = 1.  At the second UBound I receive: UBound(arrResult, 1) = 6.  At the second LBound I receive LBound(arrResult, 1) = 1.  When I hover over each arrResult, including the last one in the line of code, I receive no response.

Comment: So, the upper and lower second dimensions are the same size, indicating no matching data is being found.  Does the data you see in ClientJob and JobInfo match your sheet?  Are The client and job numbers in the first two columns?